# could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'. Could not resolve io.quarkus:gradle-application-plugin:2.10.2.Final

Tags: java, quarkus, gradle-plugin, quarkus-rest-client

I am trying to deploy quarkus application in AWS, I am getting build failed with below error. Can someone help on this? Gradle version I am using is 7.5

Thanks

Below is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.quarkus'
}

dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client'

}

group 'test.quarkus'
version '2.10'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
}

compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}




**
```

> Below is the error.

**

> > Could not resolve io.quarkus:gradle-application-plugin:2.10.2.Final.
> > Required by:
> > project : > io.quarkus:io.quarkus.gradle.plugin:2.10.2.Final
> > > No matching variant of io.quarkus:gradle-application-plugin:2.10.2.Final was found. The
> > consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with
> > Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally,
> > as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.5'
> > but:
> > - Variant 'apiElements' capability io.quarkus:gradle-application-plugin:2.10.2.Final declares a library,
> > packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> > - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the
> > consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
> > - Other compatible attribute:
> > - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
> > - Variant 'javadocElements' capability io.quarkus:gradle-application-plugin:2.10.2.Final declares a runtime
> > of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> > - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> > - Other compatible attributes:
> > - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> > - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> > - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
> > - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability io.quarkus:gradle-application-plugin:2.10.2.Final declares a runtime
> > of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared
> > externally:
> > - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a
> > component compatible with Java 8
> > - Other compatible attribute:
> > - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
> > - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability io.quarkus:gradle-application-plugin:2.10.2.Final declares a runtime
> > of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> > - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> > - Other compatible attributes:
> > - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> > - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> > - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')

Comment: Have you tried with Quarkus version 2.11.1?

Comment: I have tried, getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for delay, my friend!!! In my case, I changed the environment variables of JAVA_HOME and JAVA_JDK from Java 8 to JAVA 11.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Gradle settings change helped me.

```
Menu File -> Settings (on macOS, Android Studio -> Preferences) -> 
Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle
```

In right section of window find your project and select it.

In menu **Gradle JDK** select **JAVA 11** version .